# Calculation of number of nuclear fusion reaction per cubic meter or kilo

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

In wikipedia article about Nuclear fusion there is a list of nuclear fusion reaction [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion#Criteria_and_candidates_for_terrestrial_reactions).

Is there a equation how to calculate number of nuclear fusion reaction per second per cubic meter or per kg or per some amount of atoms depends on pressure and temperature?

For example, I would like to calculate for first reaction Deuterium + Tritium -> Helium. How many reactions per second will happen if I have 1 kg of Deuterium + 1 kg of Tritium with temperature 1000000K and pressure 1000 atmosphere. Or any other temperature/pressure, etc.

Comment: The important concept here is [nuclear cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_cross_section). Take a look at that article, it will help you to ask a more focused question. (BTW, some of your deuterium will react with itself to produce tritium).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks a lot. I will have a look. Actually I need very approximate number. Just to understand the order of the value, if it 10000 or 100000. For this purpose I believe reaction of deuterium with itself I can neglect.